# Spring @Autowired violates DRY principle. What can be done?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, dry

Some controllers and services in code I work with have a lot of `@Autowired` dependencies. There are two popular ways to autowire - Autowire fields and Autowire constructor.
In first case you duplicate annotation `@Autowired`.

```
public class SomeController {
    @Autowired
    private SomeService1 someService1;
    @Autowired
    private SomeService2 someService2;
    @Autowired
    private SomeService3 someService3;
}
```

In second case you create an ugly and useless constructor.

```
public class SomeController {
    private final SomeService1 someService1;
    private final SomeService2 someService2;
    private final SomeService3 someService3;

    @Autowired
    public SomeController(SomeService1 someService1,
                          SomeService2 someService2,
                          SomeService3 someService3) {
        this.someService1 = someService1;
        this.someService2 = someService2;
        this.someService3 = someService3;
    }
}
```

The situation becomes worse when you have a lot of fields that should be Autowired. I agree that a lot of dependencies usually mark a bad design, but this isn't my question. I want to avoid code duplication using something like `@AutowireAll`, - the annotation that will autowire all fields that possible to autowire. I searched for it, but couldn't find. The possible code would look like

```
@AutowireAll
public class SomeController {
    private SomeService1 someService1;
    private SomeService2 someService2;
    private SomeService3 someService3;
}
```

How can I avoid code duplicating?

Comment: This will get you in trouble with Jigsaw's limitation on reflection (at least, as long as you do not disable those). The "ugly-ass constructor" is in my opinion the cleaner solution.

Comment: No i dont think this is possible. @Autowired is not violating DRY in your fields. It rather clearly defines which fields you want to consider for DI. You wouldn't say for instance that using public/private access modifiers is violating DRY. Btw field injection is a bad practice and constructor injection is the suggested approach. Agreed on long constructors issue but also as you are saying this is a code smell more than anything else.

Comment: Didn't know that word library is forbidden on SO. We all use them. There is no shame in using libraries and not invent the wheel.

Comment: If anyone is interested there is a solution using Lombock `AllArgsConstructor`. So you don't need neither Constructor, nor `@Autowired` annotation, just the fields and they can be final.

Comment: It's not that specifically Word libraries are off-topic – we *all* use libraries all the time, for all programming languages. But asking *what* library to use is "off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam", per the [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 3):

It's possible to avoid code duplicating using [Lombok](https://projectlombok.org/) annotation `@AllArgsConstructor`

```
@AllArgsConstructor
public class SomeController {
    private final SomeService1 someService1;
    private final SomeService2 someService2;
    private final SomeService3 someService3;
}
```

It works in `Spring`/`Spring Boot` versions that doesn't require `@Autowired` on the only constructor. These versions are Spring Boot 1.4+, Spring 4.3+

`@AllArgsConstructor` creates a constructor what may be desirable (see  *Karol Dowbecki* comments under his answer).

The drawback is that in order to use Lombok you need a plugin for IDE. Both Eclipse and IDEA have such plugin, but as you are not the only developer working on project, all other developers will also need it.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to use `@Autowired` if there is only a single constructor. It will be auto-wired by default:

```
@Controller
public class SomeController {
  private final SomeService1 someService1;
  private final SomeService2 someService2;

  public SomeController(SomeService1 someService1, SomeService2 someService2) {
    this.someService1 = someService1;
    this.someService2 = someService2;
  }
}
```

As per [docs, chapter 1.9.2. @Autowired](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/5.0.5.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/core.html#beans-autowired-annotation):

> As of Spring Framework 4.3, an @Autowired annotation on such a
>   constructor is no longer necessary if the target bean only defines one
>   constructor to begin with. However, if several constructors are
>   available, at least one must be annotated to teach the container which
>   one to use.

Comment: But as I said, I don't want to have a constructor with a long list of arguments.

Comment: How else will you ensure that required dependencies are injected, with a `@PostConstruct`? How will you unit test the bean, with reflection or accessing the fields? Constructors have their use.

Comment: Why should I ensure that required dependencies are injected. It violates don't test framework principle. I will see NPE in any case if some of dependencies aren't injected, but I don't want to pollute the code to see it earlier (though I agree with Fail Fast ideology). Also I would prefer dirty tests to dirty code in case I should choose one.

Comment: It's like creating a `Scanner` without the reference to actual input, it doesn't make sense. Code that allows to create and use an invalid object is harder to understand and is definitely not clean. Spring Framework has a chapter on this, look for "Constructor-based or setter-based DI?" in the docs. With your `@Controller` it boils down to "The Spring team generally advocates constructor injection as it enables one to implement application components as immutable objects and to ensure that required dependencies are not null."